# Change an object's property's based on its name with python

Tags: python, scripting

I have an object in my scene named cube. Is it possible to add a particle system to that object with python by using its name?

Comment: I've provided an answer for you with script, screenshots and a .blend file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Objects are in the datablock bpy.data.objects:

```
obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
particles = obj.modifiers.new("myparticles", type="PARTICLE_SYSTEM")

#once you have the modifier, you can adjust its settings
particles.particle_system.settings.particle_size = 1.0
#and other properties
particles.particle_system.vertex_group_density = mygroup
```

More info: [ParticleSystem](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bpy.types.ParticleSystem.html#bpy.types.ParticleSystem) [ParticleSettings](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bpy.types.ParticleSettings.html#bpy.types.ParticleSettings)

Comment: Also how would I add more settings to this particle system?

Comment: Added more info to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the below script:

```
import bpy

C= bpy.context
scene = C.scene

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
objname = 'Cube' ###### Add Name of object you want here ######
ob = bpy.data.objects[objname]
ob.select = True
scene.objects.active = ob
bpy.ops.object.particle_system_add()
```

Result:

[image]

A .blend file can be downloaded from here: [image]